# System.Windows.Media in Windows phone 8.1 applications

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating a Windows Phone 8.1 (Windows Runtime) application and need to use some classes from the System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace (more precisely the BitmapDecoder class), but Visual Studio 2013 says "The type or namespace 'Media' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)".

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't do that.  Use equivalent APIs from the Windows Runtime.

Comment: Thank you! What's the equivalent for the System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace?

Comment: @Mika Have you tried to google that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [`Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder.aspx)? You don't mention exactly which features of `BitmapDecoder` you need, so it's hard to say if it will work for you.

Comment: Thank you, that will work for me. I guess WriteableBitmap is not available on Windows Runtime.